# Convert foreach to optimised code using LINQ or any other way

Tags: c#, linq

This given line of code. How can I write in a more optimized way? The below code is working fine but I need another way of writing this

```
var attachments = new List<Attachments>();
foreach (var attachment in msg.attachments) //msg.attachments is a Dictionary<string, FileAttachment> type
{
  var attach = new Attachments();
  attach.name = attachment.Value.name;
  attach.type = attachment.Value.type;

  attachments.Add(attach);
}
```

Comment: Why do you believe LINQ is "optimised"? Optimised in what way?

Comment: For working code, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is probably a better place to post. Honestly though, there seems to be nothing wrong with the code you've provided.

Comment: Yes, your code could be rewritten in LINQ, but why do you "need" it? What's wrong with your current solution?

Comment: I am not believing. I think using Linq the give lines of code will be more optimized and work fast

Comment: As Llama said, Code Review is probably the better place for your request. They would also tell you that your class `Attachments` should be singular (`Attachment`) and have a constructor taking name and type.

Comment: "*I think using Linq the give lines of code will be more optimized and work fast*" Sorry, no. (In general. It always depends on the particular case. If in doubt, measure.)

Comment: Unless you're passing the result of `.Select(attachment =>` (and not using `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()`) to a method that's designed to accept an enumerable and loop through it, you won't be gaining anything by using LINQ.

Comment: a) LINQ is unlikely to be faster. b) I would give two suggestions. Firstly, iterate over msg.attachments.Values (or if you don't want to do that, store the result of the `Value` property rather than accessing it twice). Secondly, set the capacity of the list through the constructor.

Comment: Thanks, @Llama, and Heinzi for clarification.

Comment: Before you post at [codereview.se], make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
var attachments =
    msg
        .attachments
        .Select(attachment => new Attachments()
        {
            name = attachment.Value.name,
            type = attachment.Value.type,
        })
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

> This given line of code. How can I write in a more optimized way?

You mention LINQ, but LINQ is often the *opposite* of "optimized" - it is trading *away* efficiency to gain convenience and (sometimes) terseness. There is absolutely nothing wrong with your existing code. The only *significant* tweak would be to initialize the target list with the known length:

```cs
var attachments = new List<Attachments>(msg.attachments.Count);
```

You could also do things such as using object initializer syntax on the `new Attachments`, or avoiding the multiple `.Value`, but to be honest: neither of those is likely to make an even remotely measurable difference. But:

```cs
foreach (var attachment in msg.attachments.Values)
{
  attachments.Add(new Attachments {
    name = attachment.name, type = attachment.type
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
var attachments = msg.attachments
    .Select(a => new Attachments
    {
        name = a.Value.name,
        type = a.Value.type
    })
    .ToList();
```

But as others have pointed out in the comments, this isn't really more optimised (although  a bit more readable in my opinion).

Comment: Or `msg.attachments.Values.Select(...`.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Sure, that'd work as well, but this way you can still access the key as well if you'd need it. I don't think there's much difference either way, apart from not needing to do the .Value every time.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the [linq query syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq):

```
var attachments = from att in msg.attachments 
                  select new Attachments { name = att.Value.name, type = att.Value.type };
```

If you use it like this, you will be able to make use of the [deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/deferred-execution-example).
If you really need to collapse it into a list, you can just call `.ToList()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using a LINQ lambda syntax, you can use this [comprehension query](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq):

```
var attachments = ( from attachment in msg.attachments
                    select new Attachments
                    {
                      name = attachment.Value.name,
                      type = attachment.Value.type
                    } 
                  ).ToList();
```

It select a new object instance from every items in the source collection and takes a List of the resulting query.

But for such a simple piece of code, there shouldn't be much difference, in very little gain or loss (can be benchmarked).

Thus it's just a matter of preference for clean and maintainable code.